# Matrix from dataframe in R/Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe like this:
If the person with that id has that fruit the value is 1, else it is 0. ID column is a primary key.

| ID | Apple | Orange | Pear | Grapes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| E2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| E3 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| E4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| E5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I want a output as a matrix like this. This is a count of people who has both i and j fruit. Where i and j both are same, eg: cell apple x apple, we are looking at the count of all the people who has at least an apple apple. Here, 3 people have apple, so the value is 3. Similarly, we have only one person who has both apple and orange(E4) so the count is 1 in both (orange x apple) and (apple x orange) cells. We have 2 people in the above dataframe who has both grapes and apple(E1 and E5), so value in that cell is 2.

Edits: I want output like this

|  | Apple | Orange | Pear | Grapes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| Orange | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Pear | 1 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Grapes | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

I am new to R and Python, and not sure how to achieve this. Any help in either R or Python would be really appreciated! Please feel free to ask questions if anything is not clear or anything is missing. Thanks!

Comment: why is apple and grapes 2?

Comment: E1 Has Pear, so then if you say Apple and grapes is 2 apple, apple would be 3

Comment: @ansev E1 and E5 2 people have both apple and grapes, hence count is 2

Comment: @ansev the cell (apple x apple) represents count of people who only has apple and no other fruit. None of the IDs have only apple. Everyone has apple and some other fruit. So the cell (apple x apple) is 0

Comment: @ansev if you see cell (apple x pear), it is 1 because E1 is the only person having both apple and pear. So the count of person having both apple and pear is 1, hence 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` R option:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
    filter(value > 0) %>%
    select(-value) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ expand.grid(.x$name, .x$name))) %>%
    unnest(data) %>%
    group_by(Var1, Var2) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    filter(Var1 != Var2) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Var1, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Var2   Apple  Pear Grapes Orange
#  <fct>  <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 Pear       1     0      1      1
#2 Grapes     2     1      0      0
#3 Orange     1     1      0      0
#4 Apple      0     1      2      1
```

The idea is to use `expand.grid` to generate all pairwise combinations. The rest is counting occurrences and reshaping. Re-order rows & columns as necessary.

PS. I should mention that the result is slightly different from the expected output. For example, I don't understand why (Pear, Pear) = 1. I assume this in an error. Since you're asking for co-occurrences, all diagonal elements should be zero.

---

### Sample data

```r
data <- read.table(text = "ID   Apple   Orange  Pear    Grapes
E1  1   0   1   1
E2  0   0   1   0
E3  0   1   1   0
E4  1   1   0   0
E5  1   0   0   1", header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks @Maurtis for this answer. (pear, pear) means how many people has pear and no other fruit. Hence (pear, pear) = 1 because E2 is '1' person having only pear and not any other fruit. Diagonals are supposed to mean only that fruit 'and' no other fruit.

Comment: @ella I think that is very confusing (and orthogonal to the interpretation of the off-diagonal elements). For example & based on your expected output, (apple, grapes) = 2 does *not* mean that there are 2 persons having *only* apple + grapes (and no other fruits). So you're adopting two *different* interpretations for what off and on-diagonal entries mean.

Comment: @Maurtis, that makes sense. Maybe I'll adopt what you suggested. When I am running this code on my original data frame, I get this error when mutate is used. Any suggestions on this would be very helpful. "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
i The error occurred in group 1"

Comment: Resolved that one, but new error is: Error: Assigned data value must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 3990 rows.
x Assigned data has 69 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example with Python3 and  `itertools.permutations`:

```py
import itertools

import pandas as pd

# Create original dataframe
columns = ['ID', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Grapes']
rows = [
    ['E1', 1, 0, 1, 1],
    ['E2', 0, 0, 1, 0],
    ['E3', 0, 1, 1, 0],
    ['E4', 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ['E5', 1, 0, 0, 1],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns)

# Count values of resulting matrix
def get_ones_indexes(els):
    for i, el in enumerate(els):
        if el == 1:
            yield i

res_n = len(df.columns) - 1
res = [[0] * res_n for _ in range(res_n)]

for _, row in df.drop('ID', axis=1).iterrows():
    indexes = list(get_ones_indexes(row.to_list()))

    if len(indexes) == 1:
        idx = indexes[0]
        res[idx][idx] += 1
    else:
        for i, j in itertools.permutations(indexes, 2):
            res[i][j] += 1

# Convert resultinng matrix to dataframe
_, *fruit_cols = df.columns
res_df = pd.DataFrame(res, index=fruit_cols, columns=fruit_cols)

print(res_df)
#         Apple  Orange  Pear  Grapes
# Apple       0       1     1       2
# Orange      1       0     1       0
# Pear        1       1     1       1
# Grapes      2       0     1       0
```